# Boost Deserialization into Dynamic types

Tags: c++, boost, deserialization, boost-serialization

[In this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) you can find the boost Serialization and Deserialization. But in the Deserialization method we need to give the specific object of the class to deserialize. Ex: newg

```
gps_position newg;
{
    // create and open an archive for input
    std::ifstream ifs("filename");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    // read class state from archive
    ia >> newg;
    // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
}
```

Since C++ doesnt have any base class like Object in C#, how can i deserialize into a common object and then typecast it?

As far as i no, i can create a custom class call object and inherit all the other classes from that, but even in that case there will be a situation to deserialize 2 times. Are there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Boost.serialization must be given concrete class. Since c++ don't have virtual constructors, deserializer must know what object to create. Common ancestor won't help either. Object's must be created **before** deserialization.

If you want serialize and deserialize class hierarchies, you must explicitly write class Id when serializing objects and when deserializing - explicitly read this Id to make a decision - what object to create and deserialize.

Comment: but even to read the ID i have to deserialize it first and then again deserialize to that type isnt it?

Comment: I don't think that boost serialization was designed to work with dynamic object hierarchies. Maybe I'm not right.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize into a base class if you serialize/deserialize pointers to objects. Boost then creates the Id etc. automatically. The mechanism is described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers)